# extra <<<<<<< HEAD comes on each white space when file pull from bitbucket git

Tags: php, git, cakephp, bitbucket

```
    CakePHP Version  : 2.5.4
    git version is: 1.9.0
    Sourcetree version is: 1.6.5.0
    OS: Windows.
    Bitbucket repository: git
```

hello,i have change & marge my project file with others.But, when i get/pull files from bitbucket then extra

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
<<<<<<< HEAD
```

string comes on my each page's white spaces. how can i avoid it. any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have / had a file conflict.  If you remove it and re-commit, it should go away.  Alternatively, you can check out your changes or the incoming changes

```
git checkout --ours PATH/FILE
git checkout --theirs PATH/FILE
```

Also see the following link for additional conflict resolution
[Git Conflict Resolution](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/git/git-resolve-merge-conflicts/)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the changes before merging

```
git diff <sourcebranch> <targetbranch>
```

and looking if string comes on your page